# Gauge Theory Gravity: transformation of vector potential $A'(x)$

Tags: geometric-algebras, gauge-theory

In *Gravity, Gauge Theories and Geometric Algebra* by A. Lasenby, C. Doran and S. Gull develop a theory for gravity based on the use of a position-gauge field and a rotation-gauge field. The former is introduced in order to make gauge-invariant terms of the form $\nabla_x \phi (x)$, which under diffeomorphisms $x'=f(x)$ follow the transformation law:

$$\nabla_x \phi (x) \rightarrow\nabla_x \phi' (x) =\bar{\rm f}\left(\nabla_{x'} \phi (x')\right)$$

Later on in the document, the electromagnetic vector potential is introduced. From the classical gauge invariance property $A \rightarrow A+\nabla \phi$ (although it is presented a bit differently in the text, the concept is the same), concentrating on the term $\nabla \phi$ the authors affirm the vector potential should transform in the same way as a gradient does, with the conclusion:

$$A(x) \rightarrow A'(x) =\bar{\rm f}\left(A(x')\right)$$

Although it obviously makes sense that something which can be freely varied by adding a whatever gradient should indeed transform as a gradient, the mathematical procedure needed to prove this is not entirely clear to me. I present the few passages (which I'm not sure are completely correct) I tried to develop:

- the gauge invariance of vector potential may be written as:

$$A_1(x) - A_2(x) =\nabla_x \phi(x)$$

- applying the diffeomorphism yields:

$$A'_1(x) - A'_2(x) = \bar{\rm f}\left( \nabla _{x'} \phi (x') \right)$$

- even if I change the position dependance, the relation $A_1(x') - A_2(x') =\nabla_{x'} \phi(x')$ should still hold (as from the point of view of the math, it seems equivalent to simply putting an apostrophe near the $x$), so:

$$A'_1(x) - A'_2(x) = \bar{\rm f}\left( A_1(x') - A_2(x') \right)$$

- now, for every field $A$, the following relation should hold:

$$A'(x) - \bar{\rm f}\left(A(x') \right) = K$$

where K is a constant or field (whose exact dependance I was unable to derive). Assuming the previous passages are correct, the answer to my question should be then showing that $K$ is identically equal to $0$, which is exactly what I am missing.

EDIT: I forgot to specify the notation: $\underline{\rm f}$ is the differential of the diffeomorphism $f$, while $\bar{\rm f}$ is the adjoint of the differential

Answer (score 2):

$
\newcommand\DD[2]{\frac{\mathrm d#1}{\mathrm d #2}}
\newcommand\diff\underline
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\adj\overline
\newcommand\tDD[2]{\mathrm d#1/\mathrm d#2}
$

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold, and let $f : M \to M$ be diffeomorphism. $f$ induces a transformation on the tangent bundle $TM$ by noting that a path $\gamma : [0,1] \to M$ transforms to $f\circ\gamma$. It follows by the chain rule that
$$
  \DD{}tf(\gamma(t)) = \diff f(\gamma(t);\,\tDD\gamma t).
$$
Thus at a tangent vector $v = \tDD\gamma t$ at $x = \gamma(t)$ is "pushed" to $T_{f(x)}M$ via
$$
  v \mapsto \diff f(x; v).
$$

Now consider a one-form $\alpha_x : T_xM \to \R$. Pushing this via $f$ gives
$$
  \alpha_x(v) \mapsto \alpha_{f(x)}(\diff f(x; v)) \implies
  \alpha_x \mapsto \alpha'_x = \alpha_{x'}\circ\diff f(x; {-}),
$$
where $x' = f(x)$. If the vector potential $A_x$ is to be interpreted as "transforming like a one-form", then $A_x$ is vector such that $A_x = \alpha_x^\sharp$ where $\alpha_x$ is a one-form and $\sharp : T^*_xM \to T_xM$ is the isomorphism induced by a given metric. If $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is any basis at $x$ with reciprocal $\{e^i\}_{i=1}^n$ then
$$
  v\cdot A_x = \alpha_x(v),\quad \alpha_x^\sharp = \sum_{i=1}^ne^i\alpha_x(e_i).
$$
If $\alpha_x$ transforms as above to $\alpha'_x$ then
$$\begin{aligned}
  A_x \mapsto A'_x
    &= (\alpha'_x)^\sharp
    = \sum_{i=1}^ne^i\alpha'_x(e_i)
    = \sum_{i=1}^ne^i\alpha_{x'}(\diff f(x; e_i))
\\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^ne^i(\diff f(x; e_i)\cdot A_{x'})
    = \sum_{i=1}^ne^i(e_i\cdot\adj f(x; A_{x'}))
\\
    &= \adj f(x; A_{x'}).
\end{aligned}$$

We can also do this without a basis using the following two facts. Let $\flat = \sharp^{-1}$ and let $L^* : W^* \to V^*$ denote the dual of a linear map $L : V \to W$.

1. If $L : T_xM \to \R$, then $L^* : \R \to T^*_xM$ and we can identify $L^*$ with $L$.
2. If $L : T_xM \to T_yM$, then the adjoint of $L$ under the metric is exactly $\adj L = \sharp\circ L^*\circ\flat$, and in particular $L^* = \flat\circ\adj L\circ\sharp$.
   It follows that
   $$
     A'_x
       = (\alpha'_x)^\sharp
       = (\alpha_{x'}\circ\diff f(x;{-}))^\sharp
       = \diff f^*(x; \alpha_{x'})^\sharp
       = \adj f(x; \alpha_{x'}^\sharp)
       = \adj f(x; A_{x'}).
   $$

---

First, let's note that the *proper* way of writing the transformation of $A$ should allow for gauge transformations; we should really write
$$
  A'_x + \nabla\phi(x) = \adj f(x; A_{x'}).
$$
But then
$$\begin{aligned}
  A'_x
    &= \adj f(x; A_{x'}) - \nabla\phi(x)
\\
    &= \adj f(x; A_{x'}) - \adj f\Bigl(x;\, \nabla'(\phi\circ f^{-1})(x')\Bigr)
\\
    &= \adj f\Bigl(x;\, A_{x'} - \nabla'(\phi\circ f^{-1})(x')\Bigr).
\end{aligned}$$
Here we've used the shorthand $\nabla' = \nabla_{x'}$.
This shows that such an $A'$ is in fact the transformation of $A$ in some gauge. Similarly, we can show that $A$ transforms properly to some gauge of $A'$:
$$\begin{aligned}
  A'_x
    &= \adj f(x; A_{x'} + \nabla'\phi(x'))
\\
    &= \adj f(x; A_{x'}) + \adj f(x; \nabla'\phi(x'))
\\
    &= \adj f(x; A_{x'}) + \nabla(\phi\circ f)(x),
\end{aligned}$$$$
  \implies A'_x - \nabla(\phi\circ f)(x) = \adj f(x; A_{x'})
$$

So a good question to ask is: is this still possible if $A$ transforms like a vector? In that case, if
$$
  A'_x + \nabla\phi(x) = \diff f(x; A_{x'})
$$
then for *all* $f$ and $\phi$ there must be some $\psi$ such that
$$
  \diff f(x; \nabla'\psi(x')) = \nabla\phi(x).
$$
I've not been able think of a counterexample yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The only thing which remains a little bit unclear to me is: in the presence of the metric, technically it should be possible to write any vector as the musical isomorphism of a one form ($v=\alpha ^\sharp$), so from this it would come that tangent vectors don't only transform as tangent vectors, they also transform as cotangent ones at the same time. Obviously, this cannot be true, but the why is not entirely clear to me

Comment: @Confusus I don't have a good answer, but see the section I added at the end of my post.

Comment: @Confusus With this last section in mind, it would suffice to show that the $K$ from your question is the gradient of some scalar field.

Comment: Well, if it possible to affirm somehow that $\bar{\rm f} \left(  A(x') \right)$ is still a vector potential even with the presence of $\bar{\rm f}$, then the difference $A'(x) - \bar{\rm f} \left(  A(x') \right)$ should respect the gauge invariance condition, meaning it must be a gradient of a scalar field. If we spell it out in coordinates: $\bar{\rm f} \left(  A(x') \right) = \dot{ \nabla } (\dot{f} (x) \cdot A(x') ) = \vec{e}^j \frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^j} A_i(x') = \vec{e'}^i A_i(x')$, which actually seems to resemble an untrasformed $A(x) = \vec{e}^i A_i(x)$